# Rails switch (checkbox) caching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, parameters

I have a task: I have three switches, each of them allows the user to add or remove some parts of the pdf, so basicall customize the pdf output.

So far I understood, that I need to cache the params, for this purpose I'd need to transform those switches into a kind of a "real" form, so that the input can be cached. I am super new to this, I hope, I am getting it right so far.

Thing is, as I don't really know, what am I supposed to do here, I am looking for some help online, but wasn't successfull by just googling. Maybe there are some tipps or tutorials on that, or what's the best way to search for the stey-by-step form params caching? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Comment: For now I only have switch buttons from Bulma

Comment: why do you think you need to cache the params? (Knowing nothing about your app) I can imagine that you can take the params and construct the pdf according to the values. What is the purpose of caching?

Comment: Your assumptions are right in a general case; I could do this. In our application, we use another microservice, using a headless browser, which renders another route and returns a PDF. Therefore I need to path the configuration of the PDF to another route. One way could be to add the configuration to the request the microservice call, and another way could be to cache the configuration and kind of misuse the cache for the purpose.